# Server logs an empty array when I send a JS variable via post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

When I `console.log(request.body)` the terminal logs `{}`, when I'm actually trying to log the variable `ownerSteamId`. Here is my code:

Server side JavaScript:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body)
});
```

Client side JavaScript:

```
const ownerSteamId = '76561198034202275';

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    },
    body: ownerSteamId
};
fetch('/api', options);
```

How can I make it so the server logs the value for `ownerSteamId` instead of an empty array?

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify({ownerSteamId}),`

Comment: You are setting the content type to `text/html` in your post request, so `bodyparser.json()` won't parse it and there is no other body parser attached

Comment: Trying `body: JSON.stringify({ownerSteamId})` still gives me the same issue.

Comment: Is there a content type I could set it too that would work?

Comment: if your body is JSON, you should set content-type to `application/json`  (and that is also the one, bodyparser.json() is looking for ...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bodyparser json you actually have to send `application/json` payloads to the server. You can either send valid JSON:

```
const body = {ownerSteamId: '76561198034202275'};

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
};

fetch('/api', options);
```

or you attach another Bodyparser to handle raw bodys:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```